# Convert simple data format file(.sdf) to csv

Tags: binaryfiles, file-conversion, sdf

Does anyone knows how to convert a simple data format file (extension .sdf) to csv? For more info:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b1f8/5aa762d9178a98179c5590cd9d541f8149ac.pdf

You can check also check following link: [http://solarmuri.ssl.berkeley.edu/~fisher/public/software/SDF](http://solarmuri.ssl.berkeley.edu/%7Efisher/public/software/SDF)

I have done an extensive search and there aren't much intel to help me with this problem.

Simple Data Format (SDF) is a platform-independent, precision-preserving binary data I/O format capable of handling large multi-dimensional arrays. It was written in 2007 by George H. Fisher, a researcher at the Space Sciences Laboratory at UC Berkeley, and released under the GNU General Public License.

If anyone have worked with this files and could give me an input. Thank you :-)